# How to close input timer?

Tags: python

Trying to get the program to close if an input isn't inputted in time.

```
from threading import Timer
import sys

loop = False
while(not loop):
timeout = 5
t = Timer(timeout, print, ['Sorry, times up'])
t.start()
prompt = input("Enter Y or No: \n").lower()

if prompt != None:
    t.cancel()
    if (prompt == "y") or (prompt == "n"):
        print("Correct Answer")
        loop = True
        sys.exit()
```

Currently, once it prints `Sorry, times up` the input & IF sections still run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/time-limited-input

Comment: Still new to coding & honestly don't really understand what the person is talking about

Comment: Used the first part of that answer to get what I made, but doesn't end the program after printing `Sorry, times up`

Comment: We don't understand your code because it is not indented properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt command is waiting for input from the user.
Important likns:
[Time-Limited Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15528939/11582270)
[timer objects (python) with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683411/timer-objects-python-with-)
[Why does sys.exit() not exit when called inside a thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905189/why-does-sys-exit-not-exit-when-)
The `timeIsUp` function is called after `timeout` seconds if `t.close()` is not called.

```
from threading import Timer
import sys,os

def timeIsUp():
  print("Sorry, times up")
  #os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
  os._exit(1)

loop = False
while(not loop):
 timeout = 5
 t = Timer(timeout, timeIsUp)
 t.start()
 prompt = input("Enter Y or No: \n").lower()

 if prompt != None:
    t.cancel()
    if (prompt == "y") or (prompt == "n"):
        print("Correct Answer")
        loop = True
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Using the while cycle so that if a user doesn't input Y or N it loops back till they do

Comment: @TK_ I have adjusted the answer according to the note.